# how get the cisco switch interfaces' status by snmp?

Tags: snmp, cisco, net-snmp, switching, cisco-ios

By using command line(ssh), I can get switch interfaces status like below（just demo）:

```
Cisco-Switch# show int status

Port        Name            Status      Vlan    Duplex      Speed
Eth0/1      test_alias      connected   1       a-full      a-100
Eth0/2                      notconnect  1       auto        auto
Eth0/3                      connected   3       a-full      a-100
Eth0/4                      connected   3       a-full      a-100
Eth0/5      potchann        linkFlapE   255     auto        auto
Eth0/6                      notconnect  300     auto        auto
Eth0/7                      sfpAbsent   routed  auto        auto
Eth0/8                      sfpAbsent   routed  auto        auto
Eth0/9                      connected   trunk   full        a-10G
```

By using SNMP walk(oid:.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1 or .1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1), I can get every interface name, adminStatus, operStatus and so on.
I got these  after the summary：

```
| adminStatus | OperStatus | commandLine Port Status |
|     up      |     up     |        connected        |
|     up      |    down    |        notconnect       |
|     up      |    down    |        linkFlapE        |
|     up      |    down    |        sfpAbsent        |
|    down     |    down    |        disable          |
|    down     |    down    |        sfpAbsent        |
```

abviosly, there are 3 staus when AdminStatus is up and OperStatus is down in snmp oid "1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1".
So, I think the commandLine port status cannot be fetched by this snmp oid.
finnaly, I don't find a way to get switch interface status(like "connected","notconnect","disable","sfpAbsent") in SNMP.
hoping someone can tell me the oid to resolve it.
Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the interface information is retrievable using this OID:

```
.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.7
```

Comment: already tried. that oid is OperStatus. what i want is connect, notconnect or disable, not just up or down

Comment: Try looking at these OID's https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20827/how-to-get-port-interface-status-of-cisco-switch-via-snmp

Comment: already saw this site before i submit this question, but it seems like described the color of led for switch. but i will try those oid tomorrow. thx for your help.

Comment: I tried the mibs that link included. But none of them can help me. Anyway， thx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u can try this oid `.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.8` (ifOperStatus). It should have this (1-up, 2-down, 3-testing, 4-unknown, 5-dormant, 6-notPresent, 7-lowerLayerDown) from the site I have been search for. [link](http://cric.grenoble.cnrs.fr/Administrateurs/Outils/MIBS/?oid=1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.8)

Comment: Thx. But that is not what I want, I wanna got the interface status like connect notconnect or disable